# Difference between "dramaturgic" and "dramaturgical"

Tags: word-choice

For example, I want to say that a writer has great dramaturgic(al) skills (meaning that he's good at writing original, captivating and powerful stories, able to stir the readers' emotions).

The dictionary gives the same definition for both, that is "relating to the technical aspects of drama". On Google, I found more results with "dramaturgical", but I'd like to know if the two terms can be used interchangeably.

---

I guess probably the best term to use is "dramatic" skills, as Canadian Yankee suggests. According to dictionaries "histrionic" and "theatrical" have too much to do with acting or stage performances (often in a too melodramatic way). 
I also thought of "writing skills", but it's too general. Even a person writing a résumé for a job application can have good writing skills, but it's better if he or she leaves dramatic skills aside!

Comment: Furthermore, I want to stress to you that *dramaturgy* is a far less common word than the two synonyms I have listed below: *theatrics* and *histrionics*. I say *theatrics* and *histrionics* and its adjectives all of the time; I seldom use *dramaturgy* unless I happen to be writing a paper wherein I need a synonym because I've used the same word too much.

Comment: Perhaps it's because I've actually known professional dramaturgs, but I'd use the word **dramatic** in the above sentence as meaning "good at writing good and powerful stories".  Being **dramaturgic** is writing _about_ stories, not writing the stories themselves.  A dramatist is someone who writes plays, while a dramaturg is someone who write _about_ plays.

Comment: That's one of its definitions; its other definition is "playwright".

Answer (score 2):

Both "**dramaturgic**" and "**dramaturgical**" are understood as pertaining to **dramaturgy** and are synonyms. The latter is more common between the two even as [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dramaturgic%2C%20dramaturgical&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdramaturgic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdramaturgic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDramaturgic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdramaturgical%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdramaturgical%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDramaturgical%3B%2Cc0#) tells us.

However, as both Nick and J.R. comment, it is better to use everyday words like **theatrical** *(more common)* and **histrionic** not to sound old-fashioned or overly formal.

Comment: Yeah, they mean the same thing, and other synonyms of your words above are **theatric** or **theatrical**; **histrionic** or **histrionical**. I would agree with Alexander that **dramaturgical** is more common as I have probably never said *dramatugic* although I've heard it said. As for its synonyms, **theatrical** is more common than *theatric* and **histrionic** is more common than *histrionical*, so there is no pattern regarding the ending **-al** and its being more prevalent; it just depends on the word.

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola With respect to the three words, I find "**dramaturgical**" being a more expressive and a more poetic word than either "**theatrical**" or "**histrionic**".

Comment: I agree. I'm just pointing out that it is *very uncommon*, so I pointed him to two words that a native speaker **should** know offhand. If I said *dramaturgical* to 20 native speakers, they'd **probably** all have an idea that I'm talking about **drama**; however, I would bet that more than half would not know exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola I wouldn't expect a native speaker to not know the difference between "**dramaturgical**" and "**dramatical**"

Comment: Well, the -urgy ending should give an idea that it's about writing/work such as in liturgy, but you're right; this would be construed to mean *dramatical* or *dramatic*.

Comment: @NicholasC - Right on. No learner should worry about which of these two is more common without being able to see [how rare they both are](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dramaturgic%2Cdramaturgical%2C+theatrical&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: I agree, J.R. It is unnecessary and would be highly confusing when there is a simpler term to use. I told him that the synonyms of *dramaturgical* such as *theatrical* and *histrionic* are **far more common** than this word; therefore, he should stick with those two words instead. *dramaturgical* is a great word to write in a formal paper, but it is a bad word to bandy about in common parlance.

Comment: Histrionic and theatrical have a meaning different from the one I intended. When I say the "a writer has great dramaturgical skills", I want to mean that he's great at building a powerful story able to stir the readers' emotions. But if I say that he has histrionic or theatrical skills, this writer will be a good and probably too melodramatic actor; quite a different thing! (I edited my post now)

Comment: They're still synonyms and most native speakers are not going to know "dramaturgical", but they'll know "histrionic" or "theatrical". You can use "dramaturgical" or "dramaturgic"; they mean the same thing, but it's smarter to use the ones we've pointed you to so that you might be clear to a native speaker, who, chances are, hasn't a clue what "dramaturgical" means.

Comment: @Nick "Dramatrurgical", "histrionic", and "theatrical" are *not* synoyms.

Comment: @Acccumulation Please elaborate!